# how to eval() a segment of a string

Tags: php, string, eval

I have a string that has HTML & PHP in it, when I pull the string from the database, it is echo'd to screen, but the PHP code doesn't display. The string looks like this:

```
   $string = 'Hello <?php echo 'World';?>';
   echo $string;
```

**Output**

```
   Hello
```

**Source Code**

```
   Hello <?php echo 'World';?>
```

When I look in the source code, I can see the php line there. So what I need to do is eval() just the php segment that is in the string.

One thing to consider is that the PHP could be located anywhere in the string at any given time.

*** Just to clarify, my PHP config is correct, this is a case of some PHP being dumped from the database and not rendering, because I am echo'ing a variable with the PHP code in it, it fails to run.  ***

Thanks again for any help I may receive.

Comment: Could you see the php line in the output source?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned the PHP is there in the source.

Comment: I cleared up the code a little to try and illustrate the problem a little better...

Comment: To clarify for others who may be confused about the question - What Tisch seems to be trying to do here is take a mixture of HTML and PHP out of a database and then interpolate it into another PHP source file at runtime. Most likely it's the wrong way to solve the problem, but that's what they're asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = "Hello
<?php echo 'World';?>";

$matches = array();

preg_match('/<\?php (.+) \?>/x', $str, $matches);

eval($matches[1]);
```

This will work, but like others have and will suggest, this is a terrible idea. Your application architecture should never revolve around storing code in the database.

Most simply, if you have pages that always need to display strings, store those strings in the database, not code to produce them. Real world data is more complicated than this, but must always be properly modelled in the database.

Edit: Would need adapting with preg_replace_callback to remove the source/interpolate correctly.

Comment: Thats worked a treat. Thankyou. I think I will re-evaluate how to structure my project on this advice.

Comment: Happy to help. Something like erenon's suggestion sounds good. If you want to have some dynamic functionality in your blocks, like displaying some entity, consider putting a marker/bbcode in with the html, and replace it using string/regex replacement functions

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't eval the php code, just run it. It's need to be php interpreter installed, and apache+php properly configured. Then this .php file should output Hello World.

**Answer to the edit:**
Use preg_replace_callback to get the php part, eval it, replace the input to the output, then echo it.
But. If you should eval things come from database, i'm almost sure, it's a design error.

Comment: Thank you, however this is not the case, as the line of php is in the string... and I have a variable which has the string stored in it. When I echo the variable to screen, it echo's the raw PHP code too...

Comment: Response to the 2nd Part Answer: Thankyou, I will give this a go. You're probably write about the design error! It's a personal project of mine so its all my own design... which is most probably wrong! But you live and learn :)

Comment: Keep the code in the php source files, and the content in the database. You can put e.g. bbcode tags into the database stored contents and parse them, but it's highly not recommended to mix php codes and content. It's error prone, makes security issues, bad at performance, hard to maintain, etc. Separate the code and the content. The more about the concrete problem the more i can help.

Comment: I agree with keeping things seperate. I am trying to implement a similar feature to drupal's block system... where you can write a quick block and then place it where you like. Ideally, I want to be able to echo the box where I please at a later date with something like: <?=$block[$i]['body']?>

Answer (score 0):

eval() should work fine, as long as the code is proper PHP and ends with a semicolon. How about you strip off the php tag first, then eval it.

The following example was tested and works:

```
<?php
$db_result = "<?php echo 'World';?>";
$stripped_code = str_replace('?>', '', str_replace('<?php', '', $db_result));
eval($stripped_code);
?>
```

Just make sure that whatever you retrieve from the db has been properly sanitized first, since  you're essentially allowing anyone who can get content into the db, to execute code.